# Fancy Indexing in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

What is happening here?? I'm not able to get it.

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
i = np.array( [ [0,1],[1,2] ] )
j = np.array( [ [2,1],[3,3] ] )
print(a[i,j])
```

Output looks like this

```
                 [[ 2,  5],
                 [ 7, 11]]
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: I am not able to understand what is happening behind the scenes. I want to know what happens when we do a[i,j] in this case.

Comment: @Waseem.py You may find the reason at [Indexing Multi-dimensional arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this rearrangement of the indices will help

```
[0,1],  [2,1]
[1,2],  [3,3]
```

or

```
(0,2)  (1,1)
(1,3)  (2,3)
```

It's picking 4 values, using the 4 indices from each of the 2 arrays.

a[0,2], a[1,1] etc

Comment: I understand the answer by your 2nd value of indices that you wrote. But how and why the first set of indices differs from the 2nd. ??

Comment: It's the same values, but grouped differently. Instead of all 4 `i` values together I arranged them as (i,j) pairs.  Try `a[[0.2],[1,3]]` which should give  `[a[0,1], a[2,3] ]`

Comment: Got it bro! Thank you very much :)